# Solve for $x$ correct to $3$ decimal places: $27=\frac{1}{6^x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, logarithms

$\color{white}{\require{cancel}{placeholder}}$

So recently, I decided to do some fairly basic trigonometry for fun to see what I was able to remember. I decided to give myself a challenge and attempted to solve $27=\frac{1}{6^x}$ for $x$ to $3$ decimal places. While I was able to solve the equation, I'm not sure that I was right with the answer that I achieved.

### **Here's how I got my answer:**

Set up the equation:

---

\begin{align}
27 = \frac{1}{6^x}
\end{align}

Multiply both sides by $6^x$:

---

\begin{align}
27(6^x) = \frac{1}{\cancel{6^x}}(\cancel{6^x})\iff 27(6^x) = 1
\end{align}

Divide both sides by $27$:

---

\begin{align}
\frac{\cancel{27}(6^x)}{\cancel{27}}=\frac{1}{27} & \iff 6^x = \frac{1}{27}
\end{align}

Rewrite the equation in logarithmic form: $a^b=x \implies \log_ax=b$

---

\begin{align}
\log_6\frac{1}{27}=x \iff \log_627^{-1}=x \iff -\log_627=x
\end{align}

Simplifying the logarithm, we get $x \approx -1.839$.

**This is my question:**

Was I correct with the solution that I achieved, and if not, how would I achieve the correct answer?

Comment: In which way is this a [tag:trigonometry] question?

Comment: More simply  $$27 = \frac{1}{6^x} \iff \log_6 27 =  \log_6  \frac{1}{6^x} -x$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry about that I think it was just that I forgot that even though logarithms are taught in geometry/trig class they aren't *necessarily* geometry/trigonometry

Comment: For what its worth, unless you are seeing manipulations like this for the first time there is no need to split this all up into multiple separate steps.  From $27 = \frac{1}{6^x}$ just say "*rearrange to...*" as the explanation for how to get to $6^x = 27^{-1}$ or similar.  Explicitly saying "multiply by this" and having that separate from "divide by this" is unnecessary and wordy.

Comment: As for your result, yes this is fine... even if rather trivial.

Comment: @JMoravitz  I'm relatively new (not like "woe on me" or anything) so sorry about that, I honestly need to stop putting off reading the guide on asking good questions.

Comment: Don't get me wrong... what you did on asking the question is fine.  I am just saying from a teacher's perspective or grading perspective, while I might expect a middle school student to include all of those individual steps I would hope that a highschooler would start growing out of that habit and would actively scold a college student for it.  Write according to your target audience.  If you think your audience might not be able to follow the steps to get from point A to point B then include the extra details.  At a certain point, however, it becomes unnecessary.

Comment: @JMoravitz No that's fine. I'm just saying that it's my fault in all honesty since while yes, my asking the question was fine (which I 100% agree with). In all honesty, I think the problem was that I decided to ignore the help center while writing the question, which makes it my fault because if I had read it beforehand, I would've had an easier time formulating my question and therefore would have received a more positive reaction on it.

Comment: I doubt the help center would have made much difference here, unless it made you think twice about including trigonometry as a tag. As the for rest, I do not think you've actually received much negative reaction at all. Yes, some of your work was called trivial, but "trivial" by itself is not always bad. If you were not fully comfortable with leaving out these steps, then it is still appropriate for you to have included them. I would far rather see someone include too much detail, than to see them skip steps they clearly have not mastered and thus hide where their mistakes were.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ah okay that makes sense, I also just think I just overstated the "reactions" on my post a little now that I think about it (like no offense but still) :\

Comment: Just in case you're confused by @user's comment, there's a typo: it should read $\log_627=\log_6\frac{1}{6^x}=-x$.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks! Good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct, but you don't need the various passages you show, before taking the logarithm of both sides of the equation. Therefore I suggest the simpler
$$
\log(27)=\log\left(\frac{1}{6^x}\right) \tag1
$$
Which turns into
$$
\log(27)=0-x\cdot \log(6) \tag2
$$
And solving for $x$
$$
x=-\frac{\log(27)}{\log(6)}\approx-1.839 \tag3
$$
By the way, the logarithm can be taken with any base: $e, 10, 6, 2$ and the result is still the same.

Alternatively, if you want to do something elegant that simplifies away the powers of three, you could rewrite passage (3) as
$$
x=-\frac{\log(3^3)}{\log(3\cdot2)} =-\frac{3\cdot \log(3)}{\log(3)+\log(2)}=-\frac{3}{1+\frac{\log(2)}{\log(3)}}\tag4
$$

Comment: Couldn't you rewrite passage 4 as $-\frac{3}{\log(3)}\cdot\frac{\log(3)}{\log(2)}$ or no

Comment: @CrSb0001, the log of a product is the sum of the log of the factors. You instead wrote the product of the log of the factors, which is wrong. If you calculate the  result of your suggestion, it changes depending on the base, which doesn't make sense. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

My approach, which avoids using a calculator, capitalizes on the fact that I accidentally happen to know that $~\log_{10}(2) \approx 0.301, ~\log_{10}(3) \approx 0.477.$

Therefore $~3^{(301/477)} \approx 2.$

Therefore,

$$27^{-1} = 3^{-3} = 6^x = 2^x \times 3^x \implies $$

$$3^{\frac{301x}{477}} \times 3^x \approx 3^{-3} \implies $$

$$\frac{301x}{477} + x \approx -3 \implies$$

$$\frac{778x}{477} \approx -3 \implies $$

$$x \approx \frac{-3 \times 477}{778}.$$

From here, it is just a long division problem that can be done on scratch paper.

Comment: You may notice that the approach you propose is the same shown at passage (4).

Comment: @gciriani Good point.  I had a blind spot, because I was focusing on avoiding a calculator, not realizing that someone had *peripherally beaten me to it*.

Comment: But I loved and admired your calculation by hand.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I was right, but there is a way I could do this faster:

Setting up the equation (again because why not): $$27=\frac{1}{6^x}$$
$$\implies27^{-1}=\left(\frac{1}{6^x}\right)^{-1}$$
$$\implies\frac{1}{27}=6^x$$
$$\implies\log_6\frac{1}{27}=x$$
$$\implies-\log_627=x$$
$$\implies x\,\text{is approximately}\quad-1.839$$